# Why can't I loop over $q->fetch() twice?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Assume I'm in need to loop twice with the result I got form PDO prepared statement.

First loop works fine, the next one does not work

The value of `var_dump(q->fetch())` is empty array. Any ideas?

```php
<?php
$q = $dbconnection->prepare("SELECT * from users WHERE role=?");
$q->execute(array('$id')); //Boolean true or false
    

// first loop                           
while ($row = $q->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    echo "<br/>" .  $row['user_id'] . "--". $row['fname']. "</br>";
}

// second loop  this loop will NOT echo any thing ?!
while ($row = $q->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    echo "<br/>" .  $row['user_id'] . "--". $row['fname']. "</br>";
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you loop the row, you empty out the result set. If you want to loop over multiple times, you can use `fetchAll()`, store that in a variable and loop that where you need using a `foreach` loop.

```
$q = $dbconnection->prepare("SELECT * from users WHERE role=?");
$q->execute(array($id)); //Boolean true or false

$res = $q->fetchAll();

foreach ($res as $row) {
    echo "<br/>" .  $row['user_id'] . "--". $row['fname']. "</br>";
}

foreach ($res as $row) {
    echo "<br/>" .  $row['user_id'] . "--". $row['fname']. "</br>";
}
```

Alternatively, you can execute the query again, but if you do that, you make a double query to the database. So you query twice for the same data, which isn't very efficient.

Also you had `execute(array('$id'))`, which would be the exact string `$id`, and not the variable representation. See [the PHP manual on strings](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.single). So it should be `execute(array($id))` instead.

- [PHP.net on `PDOStatement::fetchAll()`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php)

Answer (score 2):

Your are fecth a row time by time if you need  two iteration you should perform a copy eg storing rows

```
  while ($row = $q->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
      echo "<br/>" .  $row['user_id'] . "--". $row['fname']. "</br>";
      $my_rows[] = $row;
  }



   // second loop  this loop will NOT echo any thing ?!
  foreach($my_rows as $key=>$value){
            echo "<br/>" .  $value['user_id'] . "--". $value['fname']. "</br>";
  }
```